# Eclipse : How to see Design View of Html ? not in browser, but while as per i am typing

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

In Eclipse , How to see the Design View of Html side by side , not in browser.

using Eclipse Luna and i used ,

cntl+_ and cntl_{

But i splits the view in two same view (source) . I want to see the next view in Design view.

Answer (score 0):

right click on HTML/JSP file in the project explorer, and open with web page editor. shortcut key is ( shift + control + f9 ) . thats all